# Windows XP Embedded not installing new hardware

Tags: windows-xp, usb, drivers, hardware-detection

We have a Hurco VM10U milling machine running Windows XP Embedded (XPe) 6.06 and we're trying to add a Quatech QSU2-100 USB to RS-232 hub to expand some features. The hub was supplied with a drivers CD and the connection to the PC is via a USB add-in card.

When the machine is powered on, the Found New Hardware wizard does not appear. Looking in Device Manager, I can't see the hub and scanning for new hardware reveals nothing new. I've tried to install the drivers using the Add New Hardware program in Control Panel and can see and select the two `.inf` files but I then can't do anything with them; the wizard will not allow me to proceed as the Next button is ghosted.

I know the USB ports work as Hurco engineers have used them when servicing the machine. I've asked Hurco for support but they're not being very helpful and are advising I get a engineer on site at cost which I'm reluctant to do just yet.

This feels like a communication problem between the QSU2 and the PC but there's not much more I can troubleshoot hardware-wise; it's just a cable and I've tried a different one. It's been a while since I've used XP and I can't remember if there's any other way of forcing in a new bit of hardware to the OS.

The only other thing I can think of at the moment is copying the driver files directly into the file system but if there is a communication problem, this won't resolve anything.

Any help or suggestions welcome!

Comment: Did you try the new hardware on a different PC yet? It could just be DOA.

Comment: I would contact support for the manufacturer of the usb-232 hub.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this has been marked down? It would be nice for the people responsible to add a comment on why they've done this.

Comment: @DanielB - Yes, we've tried the hub on a W7 laptop and it picks up fine, unfortunately we don't have any XP machines to try this on.

Comment: @Moab - The hub is fine it would seem, see above.

Comment: Votes are anonymous, some people have nothing better to do than downvote legit questions like yours.

Comment: @RichM see this page....https://wunger.wordpress.com/category/windows-xp-embedded/

Comment: Thanks @Moab, appreciate your comments. I'll check this link out.